# Conversion of functional components in react into class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very basic question I have an array of JSONs and I could easily coopy them in functional component using

```
const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      setElements(elements => [...elements, ...data]);
    };
    res();
  }, []);
```

I want to convert them into class based components and when I try to copy in setState I get []. Code is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Element from './components/Element';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { elements: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ elements: data });
    };
    res();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.elements);
    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div id='table'>
          {this.state.elements.map(element => (
            <Element elements={element} key={element._id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is a JSON which I am getting

```
(119) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

Comment: this.setState({ elements: data }) will solve your issue

Comment: Did not work updated full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with how you're trying to set state on your React component, maybe you could try something like the following:

```
this.setState({ elements: data});
```

Can you try updating your `componentDidMount()` to the following:

```
async componentDidMount() {
 const {data} = await Axios.get('/data');
 this.setState({ elements: data });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: `setState` accepts a function or an object, both patterns are valid

Comment: Try updating your `componentDidMount()` method, I updated my answer for how it should look

Answer (score 1):

to make code equal it should be written as this

```
this.setState(state => ({
   elements: [...state.elements, ...data]
}));
```

Comment: @vinayak_shahdeo i also updated ny answer, hopefully it will work